# Can we use user record ID to assign record name when creating CKRecordID?

Tags: objective-c, cloudkit, ckrecord

Apparently we can't because it keeps throwing error whenever I try to set my own user `record ID` to create `CKRecordID` in order to create a record.
If we can't use each user's unique `recordID` for record name, what's the point in setting its name in the first place? And also, how do we distinguish between users when fetching data?

```
CKRecordID *artworkRecordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:RANDOM_UNIQUE_NUMBER];
        CKRecord *artworkRecord = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"person" recordID:recordID];
        artworkRecord[@"language"] = @"English";

        CKContainer *myContainer = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
        CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [myContainer privateCloudDatabase];
        [privateDatabase saveRecord:artworkRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord *artworkRecord, NSError *error){
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Success!");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Failure!");
            }
        }];
```

**EDIT**

I've worked it out.
So when you save/add data, record name doesn't matter at all because you'd only get your own data from PRIVATE DATA using your own user record ID hence you could set it as @"whatever" and it wouldn't matter at all.

I still don't understand a few things.

Why do we have to set record name for private data when we don't even use that in order to fetch data?

```
-(void)fetchRecord {
CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
CKReference *reference = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID:self.cloudRecordID action:CKReferenceActionNone];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creatorUserRecordID = %@", reference];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"person" predicate:predicate];
[privateDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else {
        if (![results firstObject]) {
        }
        else {
            for (CKRecord *record in results) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[record objectForKey:@"language"]);
            }
        }
    }
}];}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not work. Settings the record ID ist just for updating an existing one without fetching it. So you can create a "person" and save it's CKRecordID (or name and zone of it) to your NSUserDefaults or the private cloud database for example.
Or you save the UUID to the person object, so you can identify a person by device...

You don't have to distinguish the users. If you work on the private space, it's only for the user and you won't see data of others. And on the public space all belongs to all users of your app. (See CKContainer privateCloudDatabase and publicCloudDatabase)

If you want to handle belongings in public, use an own attribute.

Comment: Oh in fact, I am saving it as private data. So when working with private instead of public there is no need for me to check whether it's the right user huh? I'm reading Apple's doc regarding CloudKit but it does not mention anything about that matter. Also, I should just give record name some randomly generated string since it doesn't even matter..?

Comment: From the docs: "Access to the database is limited to the user of that iCloud account by default. The current user owns all content in the private database and is allowed to read and write that content. Data in the private database is not visible in the developer portal or to any other users." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CKContainer/privateCloudDatabase

Comment: Well, so what you're saying is that setting a unique record name is pointless when it comes to private date but still for fetching data we do need to identify which data is of which user..? Then the whole point of private data only being accesible by its own user doesn't help.. I still need to set unique record names in order to find out which data needs to be fetch for each user.

Comment: Also, the reason why I'm trying to set unique user record ID that comes from each users iCloud account is to allow users have access to the same data in any device but if I did what you're suggesting which is using UUID, it wouldn't work..

Comment: Ok I've managed to make it work.. so turns out when fetching there's no need of record name you previously set? I've just edited my question. Let me know if I'm doing it right....!

Comment: I think I don't get what you mean... What are you planning to achieve? Your NSPredicate tells the query which entries to fetch... but if you only want the entries from yourself, there won't be any other in your private database... you can fetch ALL with [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES] and they are all from YOUR Cloud Id, because it's your private cloud.

Comment: do you need multiple entries or just ONE? If just need one entry for data synced on all devices, simply use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore and don't bother with Cloudkit.

Comment: Then I really don't understand why we're even setting recordID when creating a record for the first time because we never use that to fetch private data.. and no not just 1 but just a few. I need about 5 entries and they're all short strings. I'm reading about NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore and it sounds promising but wouldn't I still need to use CloudKit to check whether user is logged-in anyway..?

Comment: If you store more then one entry, you can use the record id to get the specific entry... but if you are only storing one, you don't need it.
For example you are saving memos to your private cloud database. your app should remember the last opened memo, so you store the name and zone of the CKRecordID of you open memo to your NSUserDefaults. - So if you are entering the app, you can fetch this specific memo with CKRecordId initialized by name and zone from nsuserdefaults.
if you always fetch all, or fetch by other attributes, you don't need the record Id.

Comment: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore can be used even if the user is not logged in. But then, the data will not be synchronized.

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood "entry". Yes I only need 1 entry so I guess I could use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore as immediate synchronization is not needed in my case but I've already set up CloudKit and it works great so now I wonder if I should go back and use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore instead... would that worth it?

Comment: CloudKit is a big thing, a whole database and the whole Cloudkit Framework must be compiled into your app. And you need an active icloud account and you have to check that. - With NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore you need nothing. Just use it. - if the user connects to icloud it's synchronized. - Keep your code seperate, when you need a bit more. but keep your current app lightweight. just my opinion.

Comment: Yup I'm getting rid of CloudKit and implementing NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore instead. Thank you so much for your help!!